# Enhanced look up filters fields are not being display on customer portal

Tags: visualforce, customer-portal, lookup

I have created a Enhanced look up filter on an object but these enhanced lookup filter fields are not being displayed on Customer Portal. I have given all permissions on object and fields but still field are not being shown.

Do you guys have any idea why enhanced look up fields are not being display on Customer Portal?

Thanks

Comment: Did you double checked FLS is visible ?

Comment: Yes i checked twice